# How can I view this encoded file?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

I receive data every day from a client, but I can't read it. It's an encoded file. If I open it directly with `cat`, `less` or `vi`, I can't read it.

The customer shared the data file as `file_name.ZIP.zip`  (120 Mb). After I extracted the contents I got one more zip file like `file_name.ZIP.zip` (120 Mb) and `file_name.ZIP` (125 mb). Once again extracting I get `file_name` (4-5 GB) with file type `application/octet-stream; charset=binary format`.

NOTE: I receive the file in some different formats, like binary, ISO8859, etc.

Sample data:

```
$ hexdump -C file_name | head 
00000000 40 40 40 40 60 60 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 |@@@@``@@@@@@@@@@|
00000010 40 40 40 40 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |@@@@@...........|
00000020 00 00 00 00 00 60 60 40 40 40 40 40 40 60 60 40 |.....``@@@@@@``@|
00000030 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 |@@@@@@@@@@......|
00000040 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 60 40 40 40 40 |..........``@@@@|
00000050 40 40 60 60 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 00 00 |@@``@@@@@@@@@@..|
00000060 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 60 |..............``|
00000070 40 40 40 40 40 40 60 60 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 |@@@@@@``@@@@@@@@|
00000080 40 40 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |@@@.............|
00000090 00 00 00 60 60 40 40 40 40 40 40 60 60 40 40 40 |...``@@@@@@``@@@|
```

Checking the file format/type,

```
$ file -bi file_name
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Afterwards I tried to change the file format using `iconv -l`,

```
iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 file_name > New_file_name.txt;
```

or

```
iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t utf-8 file_name -o New_file_name.txt;
```

How can I decode or view this file in human readable format?

If I use hexdump,

```
$ hexdump -C file_name | head
00000000  40 40 40 40 60 60 40 40  40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40  |@@@@``@@@@@@@@@@|
00000010  40 40 40 40 40 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@@@@@...........|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 60 60 40  40 40 40 40 40 60 60 40  |.....``@@@@@@``@|
00000030  40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40  40 40 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@@@@@@@@@@......|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 60 60 40 40 40 40  |..........``@@@@|
00000050  40 40 60 60 40 40 40 40  40 40 40 40 40 40 00 00  |@@``@@@@@@@@@@..|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 60 60  |..............``|
00000070  40 40 40 40 40 40 60 60  40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40  |@@@@@@``@@@@@@@@|
00000080  40 40 40 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@@@.............|
00000090  00 00 00 60 60 40 40 40  40 40 40 60 60 40 40 40  |...``@@@@@@``@@@|
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer. You need to ask your client what he has done to the data.

Comment: Any other way or any idea based on script to do?

Comment: I already told you it is impossible to answer without know what **your** client has done to the data. We are not mind readers or psychic.

Comment: If it's not a text file, `cat` will show you junk. `xxd` will show the underlying data. *If you're willing to share that*, someone here *might* be able and willing to make sense of it. But really you should ask the client, as @DavidPostill said. It's their data; they should know how it's encoded.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I knew you were going to write that.

Answer (score 2):

It is inappropriate to use iconv on non-text files.

What you can do is use a hex-dump program to view the contents of a binary file.

```
$ hexdump -C binary.data | head
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  02 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  c0 0e 40 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.......@.....|
00000020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  80 56 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@........V......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00  08 00 40 00 1f 00 1e 00  |....@.8...@.....|
00000040  06 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000050  40 00 40 00 00 00 00 00  40 00 40 00 00 00 00 00  |@.@.....@.@.....|
00000060  c0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  c0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 02 40 00 00 00 00 00  |..........@.....|
00000090  00 02 40 00 00 00 00 00  1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..@.............|
```

In many cases, this will not be immediately enlightening, you need to do one of two things

- Get a specification for the file format and obtain or write a decoder that presents the data in human readable form.
- Use any knowledge of the content domain and deductive reasoning to examine the binary contents and work out (reverse engineer) the structure and meaning. This is usually hard work.

Comment: Thanks you, but I have the data in **text** format , how to see? if i am using  **hexdump** i am also getting same result in binary format.

Comment: @karthickkumar: The data you posted really doesn't look like a text format at all. Those "^@" signs are usually nulls. Maybe it is MS-Word, Excel or something like that. Please edit your question and paste in 20 lines of hexdump output.

Comment: @karthickkumar: Its better you use the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1112764/edit) link under your question ate edit the question itself and add the new information there. Above the editing area are icons for formatting, use the `{}` icon for *code*